# Pixel changeListener java

Tags: java, listener, pixel

is there a way in java to add a changeListener to a screen pixel?

the idea is that the pixel notify a class that it has changed its color, without having to iterate between all pixels to see which one has changed

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the color can you fire a PropertyChangeEvent, and then attach a PropertyChangeListener to handle it?

Comment: Hi Hank, thanks a lot for the answer, in this case not really, what im trying to do is to develop something similar to VNC or Teamviewer, but i want that the client only transmit to the server the pixels of his or her screen which has changed, not the whole image. i do not control the change of the pixels color !

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm not sure if there will be a way without iterating through the pixels to compare them. Since you need to find the pixels that have changed to send them on, it seems like you'll have to check each one. You could possibly hash the images and compare the hash. If they differ you know the image has been changed, and then iterate through. However, there would a slight (very, very slight) probability that you get two images that hash to the same value but are different. If that's a chance you are willing to take it would help.

Comment: Hi Hank, thanks a lot again for the answer, your answer gave me an idea, i could divide the screen capture into lets say 8 rectangles and compare the hashes of them. if i only have one hash, it will always change due to mouse movement over the screen. once again thanks a lot !!!